# How can I save an answer to my SO Account?

Tags: discussion, android-app, bookmarks

Regarding the website and the Android application: How can I save a question or the responses to a question for my future reference?

Comment: You can click on the star underneath the question and add it to your favorites, which you can then access later via the tab on your profile page. I don't think that you can do this with individual answers, though.

Comment: I usually just bookmark them, though of course that does not move platform to platform.

Comment: One of the [site's users](http://stackoverflow.com/users/130929/systempuntoout) created a useful little tool that can help you export the contents of a post to be saved off-site - http://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite

Comment: Or click the "share" link below a specific answer, and bookmark the link it gives you.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star which is itself a duplicate.

Comment: FYI: I did do a search prior to asking the question; there were no relevant answers.

Comment: It's only a duplicate if you reformat the question to follow the format of the answer. Other than that....

Answer (score 13):

Isn't this what the favorite star (now bookmark button) is for?

Just click on the star under the vote count and the question will appear in your profile page under the favorite question tab.

Comment: Yes, but there's no Starring option for a specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### For saving a question:

what [Toby Allen previously top-voted answer above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289385/2361131) (i.e. *the bookmark-star button on the left*)

#### For answers:

there is now a "Follow" button available "per-answer" too (right next to Share, Edit... below the answer)

Hurray! *throws confetti*
 not sure since when though lol (is there a stackoverflow guide that explains the release notes i wonder)

Comment: [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661)